# Response Data Analyse in JMETER

Tags: xml, http, parsing, jmeter, request

I am sending an HTTP Request to my webservice and I would like to know if it's possible in JMETER to extract the Response Data Body. My response is an XML, and I would like to analyse or extract it. For example, there is an attribute   `<response>acknowledge</response>` that I would like to extract. For example, if the response isn't "acknowledge", the request isn't good. Analyzing it would help me.

Any help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/) in order to get the `response` attribute value from the response data.

The relevant [XPath query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) would be as simple as `//response`

[image]

If you want to conditionally fail the sampler if the `response` value is `acknowledge` you can add [XPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) and use the following query there:

```
//response/text()!='acknowledge'
```

This way if the response text will be `acknowledge` - the sampler will be marked as failed, otherwise it will be "green'

[image]